# "Vu" ou "vue", que choisir ?

Tags: accord, participe-passé

Je voudrais savoir si je dois dire "Vu de l'extérieur" ou "Vue de l'extérieur" ?

Comment: Welcome to French Language SE. You're invited to take [the tour](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour) or visit the [Help Centre](https://french.stackexchange.com/help), and of course to keep asking questions. Note that this is not a homework-solving service and simply giving a short deadline isn't the best manners. The best questions for this site are ones where you're seeking to deepen your understanding of French rather than just choose between options A and B. All the best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tout dépend du contexte dans lequel tu emploies cette expression.

Selon les cas, "vu" peut être une préposition, un nom, un adjectif... Sa terminaison va alors varier.

Par exemple :

> **La** tour semble immense vu**e** de l'extérieur.

ou

> **Le** discours de ce président semble assez vide **vu** de l'extérieur.

Answer (score 4):

1. *Vu* is a past participle meaning "seen".

   *Vue* is *vu* when it agrees with a feminine noun.

So compare these two phrases where *vu(e)* is the past participle:

> Le château **vu** de l'extérieur
>   
> <sub>The castle **seen** from outside.</sub>
>
> La maison **vue** de l'extérieur
>   
> <sub>The house **seen** from outside.</sub>

2. *Vue* is also a noun meaning "view".

> Voici **la vue** de l'extérieur
>   
> <sub>Look at **the view** from outside.</sub>